# Оптимизация SQL запроса на MSSQL

Tags: sql

Как можно оптимизировать запрос?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ваши `(x like v1 and y like v2) OR (x like v1 and y like v3)` можно заменить на `(x like v1 AND (y like v2 or y like v3))` (это по крайней мере более читаемо) но я бы  на вашем месте задумался о структуре БД, либо полнотекстовом поиске.

Answer (score 1):

Какой кошмар...

Никак его не оптимизируешь, так как используется `LIKE`, который вырубает поиск по индексу.

Имеет смысл подумать над структурой БД.

Если честно, я не понимаю, зачем в поиске по номеру использовать `LIKE`. Вы по коду города фильтруете? Вынесите его в отдельную колонку.

С контрактами тоже неясно. У вас в одном поле название контракта и его номер и вы пытаетесь по LIKE `отфлитровать` по какому-нибудь номеру? Вынесите это опять в же в отдельную колонку и вы сможете искать по точному равенству с использованием индекса.

Comment: в случаях когда шаблон не начинается с `%` (то есть вида `qwe%`) то `like`  использует индекс.

Comment: @teran это да..